# bash script to copy file into multiple specified directories

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm looking to create a script that takes a file and copies the file to multiple directories

e.g. `cp2dir filename dir1/ dir2/ dir3/`

I've dug around and it looks like my route is to use `cat <inputfile> | tee <outputfile> <outputfile> <outputfile>` however, previous scripts that I have found appear to be using static files/directories.

How do I go about doing this with user input?

I'm thinking:

```
for i in $dir; do
    cat $file | tee $i
```

Where $dir and $file are user input. Would I need to `cut -d\` $dir?

Comment: The `cat | tee` combination wouldn't work well.  First, you'd need to do `cat $file | tee $i/$(basename $file)` (and worry about spaces in names, but that's a separate exercise).  Then, using `cat | tee` means the contents of the file has to be processed by two processes, instead of just one if you use `cp` in the way shown in the answers.  If you wanted to use `tee`, you might be able to justify `cat $file | tee $(for i in $dir; do echo $i/$(basename $file); done)`, but it is an unorthodox way of writing the script (but an excellent demonstration of why you use `$(...)` instead of backticks).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cp2dir() {
    local file="$1"
    shift
    local -a dirs=( "$@" )

    for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
        cp "$file" "$dir"
    done
}
```

Of course, this doesn't do any safety checks, like making sure the targets are actually directories. I leave that to you.

Comment: The local array `dirs` seems like overkill to me.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it's not necessary, but I felt it was better self-documenting than just looping over the pp.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for this @kojiro. I don't know why I brain farted and didn't think of this, but you've been a great help. I've added in checks, but now I can't figure out why the thing isn't even running the function. I'd also like to figure out how to fix the output of the successful copyall and condense to one line.

[link to script](http://pastebin.com/iugBXndH)

Comment: @kojiro you are a god among men.

Answer (score 3):

```
cp2dir() {
    local file="$1" dir
    shift

    for dir in "$@"; do
        cp "$file" "$dir"
    done
}
```